# Project Tango - System Unavailable

Tags: initialization, google-project-tango

When attempting to run any application on the Google Project Tango, I get the error "System Unavailable. Restart the app or reboot the device". I have attempted both options, but still can't get it to run.

When running the Project Tango Expolorer, I immediately get the "Failed to connect to Tango" message.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Project Tango Core is up-to-date. It should automatically update, but for some reasons (network) it can block.